# What does "can only heal so much" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found the following sentence in an American novel (this one: [here](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Everything_After/gKbiDwAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%20a%20body%20can%20only%20heal%20so%20much%22&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover) you can read the whole paragraph). A woman broke her wrist and just had her cast removed. She thinks she can start playing piano again, but her wrist still hurts too much.
I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the final sentence:

> But a body can only heal so much, so fast.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [look up **so** in a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so#English) you will see that some meanings are "to the extent" or "to such an extent/degree." In fact **so much** has its own entry [at wiktionary.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_much#English)

"*Only* so much so fast" is a limiting expression; the implication is that the body can heal some amount *and no more* in a set amount of time *and no less*. The character is expressing resignation/acceptance of her situation: she would rather be fully healed but knows it is unrealistic to expect that so soon after her accident.

"So much" can also mean "to a *great* extent" as in the phrase "My, you've grown so much since I last saw you!" Its a very versatile phrase.